# Close down all background iPhone apps without clearing task switcher (Jailbreak)

Tags: memory, iphone, multitasking

I have a 3GS running 5.1. Memory management is key to keeping it running smoothly. 
I've tried:

- SBSettings processes. Clears apps one by one and clears memory - and leaves them in the task switcher. But you have to clear one by one
- RemoveBG. One press but removes all apps from task switcher
- WeeCloseApps - as above.

Is there a tweak or app that can:

- clear all running apps in one press
- leave all apps in the task switcher
- clean up memory

This is because I use the task switcher as a "recent used apps" list - which is sort of Apple's model - for example, when you reboot iPhone no apps are running in the background, but the task switcher is still populated with your recently used apps.

Comment: Reboot the phone! Clears all running apps but keeps task switcher content.

Comment: That certainly does it - but takes ages.  When some apps crash (eg Safari) they dump you back to the homescreen, clear all the RAM and leave the apps in the task switcher. Maybe I should just find an app that crashes consistently!